# Usage of Indefinite Article "a"

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

I am wondering whether the article "a" is correctly used in this sentence.

The context is the following:

Line 1: `mystringexample = "Hello, world"`

How to read line 1: it has **a** left had side, **a** right hand side and the equals sign connects them.

Is it correct to use article "a" in the above sentence? If yes, in what sense?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the left-hand side exists and is singular.

Comment: Even without the article we know it exists, since it is written just line above. I think "the" is more appropriate suing that logic. (if articles abide by logic at all)

Comment: Would you say, showing the word to pupils on their computer screens, 'Consider the word _apparel_. It contains two _a_'s and the _e_' or  'Consider the word _apparel_. It contains two _a_'s and an _e_'? (They've already seen the _a_'s and _e_.) The 'e' is being introduced (admittedly part B; the pupils have already seen it in the word) by the teacher. The indefinite article is idiomatic here.

Comment: "the" isn't appropriate here, because "mystringexample" is not the only possible left-hand size

Comment: Idiomatically, almost every native Anglophone would use the ***indefinite*** article before both the left-hand and the right-hand side in the cited context. But I'm sure that people would be much more evenly split over whether to follow that with *and **a / the** equals sign **connects / connecting** them*. Using the continuous verb form relies on the parallel structure whereby *and [**it has**] an equals sign **connecting** them* allows us to "delete" predictably-repeated ***it has***.

Comment: Thanks all. Now it's 100% clear, why the author (he is Anglophone BTW) uses indefinite article in the part of the sentence where I asked. If you wish to earn reputation for your help please put your comments in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The issue that FumbelFingers arose about connects/connecting is really interesting. Thanks.